# Pass array of get parameters to twig template

Tags: php, symfony

I have an array of twig get parrameters created with the following code:

```
$vars = get_defined_vars();
```

How can I pass it to twig tempalate, so that I can pass that as slugs variable? For example:

```
<a href="{{ path('route_name', {vars}}))">link</a>
```

The above of course does not work, as it's the wrong format. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an associative array :

```
$vars = array( 'param1' => 'val1', 'param2' => 'val2' );
// then passed to the template as 'vars'
```

This works in Twig :

```
<a href="{{ path('route_name', vars) }}">link</a>
```